# How to refresh AMP Cache?

Tags: caching, refresh, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I have an article page with AMP (on an subdomain).
Now I have made a few changes in an article.
How can I reload this cached AMP (sub-)page?

**Normal Version:** https://www.example.com/this-is-a-article-999

**AMP-Version:** https://amp.example.com/this-is-a-article-999

**i do following steps:**

**1.** I have installed openssl on my server

**2.** Then I generated the two keys

*openssl genrsa 2048 > private-key.pem*

*openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -pubout >public-key.pem*

**3.** I copied the public key to the subdomain (= AMP page) and renamed it to "apikey.pub"

So the public key is accessible over the browser:
https://amp.example.com/apikey.pub

**4.** Then I have created the update-cache request as follow:

get a timestamp with "date +%s"

*echo -n >url.txt '/update-cache/c/s/amp.example.com/this-is-a-article-999?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1526997689' cat url.txt | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem >signature.bin*

**5.** I used the public key to verify the signature:

*openssl dgst -sha256 -signature signature.bin -verify public-key.pem url.txt*

I get the followind Error:
==> **Verification Failure** (!!!)

Answer (score 2):

On step 3, the placement of the public key is wrong. The correct one would be: `https://amp.example.com/.well-known/amphtml/apikey.pub`

The issue with the verification seems to be on step 4, as there are 2 commands being invoked on single line and generating invalid output.

The solution is to break it in 2 parts:

```
echo -n >url.txt '/update-cache/c/s/amp.example.com/this-is-a-article-999?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1526997689' 
cat url.txt | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem >signature.bin
```

or to add an & between the 2 commands:

```
echo -n > url.txt '/update-cache/c/s/amp.example.com/this-is-a-article-999?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1526997689' & cat url.txt | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem > signature.bin
```

The full sequence becomes something like this:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 > private-key.pem
openssl rsa -in private-key.pem -pubout > public-key.pem
echo -n > url.txt '/update-cache/c/s/amp.example.com/this-is-a-article-999?amp_action=flush&amp_ts=1526997689'
cat url.txt | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key.pem > signature.bin
openssl dgst -sha256 -signature signature.bin -verify public-key.pem url.txt
```

and the output is the following:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -signature signature.bin -verify public-key.pem url.txt
Verified OK
```

Another couple of things is that after generating the signature, it must be appended to the URL on the `amp_url_signature` parameter, using a [web-safe variant of Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications).

At last, make sure to check the [parameters](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/update-cache#parameters) section of the documentation and generating the URLs according to the [AMP Cache URL Format](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#amp-cache-url-format).